# Basic jQuery image gallery with thumbnails

Tags: jquery

I have a basic image gallery with four thumbnails and four large images one of which is shown, I would like to be able to click on each thumbnail and replace the active large image with the corresponding large image to what was clicked, before I was able to change a single part of the source as below, but this option will no longer work as I can no longer depend on the src of the image:

```
jQuery('#thumbs').delegate('img','click', function() {
    jQuery('#panel img').attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('99_99','600_399'));
});
```

I have dynamically added each of the four images and thumbnails into two arrays:

```
var large_photos = jQuery('#panel').find('img').map(function(){
    return jQuery(this).attr('src');
}).get();

var thumbnails = jQuery('#thumbs').find('img').map(function(){
    return jQuery(this).attr('src');
}).get();
```

How can I amend the script so that I can click on a thumbnail and the larger image is displayed?

HTML:

```
<div id="panel">
    <img src="/cache/data/691294/IMGP1617_600_399_s_c1.JPG" alt="" width="600" height="399" />
    <img src="/cache/data/691294/IMGP1618_600_399_s_c1.JPG" alt="" width="600" height="399" style="display: none;" />
    <img src="/cache/data/691294/IMGP1619_600_399_s_c1.JPG" alt="" width="600" height="399" style="display: none;" />
    <img src="/cache/data/691294/IMGP1620_600_399_s_c1.JPG" alt="" width="600" height="399" style="display: none;" />
</div>

<div id="thumbs">
    <img src="/cache/data/691294/IMGP1617_99_99_c1.JPG" alt="" width="99" height="99" />
    <img src="/cache/data/691294/IMGP1618_99_99_c1.JPG" alt="" width="99" height="99" />
    <img src="/cache/data/691294/IMGP1619_99_99_c1.JPG" alt="" width="99" height="99" />
    <img src="/cache/data/691294/IMGP1620_99_99_c1.JPG" alt="" width="99" height="99" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses the index of the clicked thumb to add a class to the corresponding index of the large image.

```
$('#thumbs img').click( function() {
    var thumbindex = $(this).index();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('#panel img').eq(thumbindex).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: I've tested this out and it works pretty well thanks, is there any way to remove the active class from all other images when the class active is assigned to an image, at present it retains the class for all images?

Comment: Call `$('.active').removeClass('active');` before you add the active class